# c# Many Unmanaged Memory in WinForm Application

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, unmanaged, ram

I've a c# winform application. Now after startup when the mainscreen is shown, I've a huge amount of unmanaged memory about 110MB, the whole managed ram is about 20 MB.

Here some things that could be uncommon:

- The application consists of many assemblies which are in total 98 MB file size.
- Some Forms have a wpfhost, but which are loaded this time (but perhaps some other WPF framework libraries)
- The Ram does not seem to be growing.
- There are  a lot strings shown many of them are part of the WPF like "margin"
- The Main form is quite big and has a infragistics datagrif with about 30 Rows.

When I load all assemblies with **Assembly.Load** in a console app they only cost 1 MB of unmanaged ram.

Where can this unmanaged memory come from ?
Can someone give me a hint on what kind of elements could be involved?

Comment: A heap profiler should show this. Have you tried one? (There is one from MS, I believe dotTrace, WinDbg and likely others might have similar capabilities)

Comment: Now can you recommend one ? I never head of this. I only use currently ANTS Profiler. a long time ago I uses SOS and Windbg. Can you give me some resources on how to heap profile in .net?

Comment: If I remembered the name, I'd have mentioned it. However, 'heap profiler .NET' is a very google-friendly term. I reckon it would have taken less time than asking me in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Profiler your code with tools and analysis solution!

•**There are a lot strings shown many of them are part of the WPF like "margin"**

Be careful with the use of "Strings"! The garbage collector does not like and tend to pick up a lot of waste if the treatment is well done.

I suggest you a very good program that will help to show when and where the memory allocated in your application!
"**CLR Profiler**" by microsoft. Is a great tool for application. Net, C # Asp. Spéciallement studied for applications using the garbage collector to calculate the performance and size of memory allocated to the aplication.
I myself used and allowed me to greatly reduce memory usage.

[How use clr profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx)

[Download clr profiler](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/4/2/442d67c7-a1c1-4884-9715-803a7b485b82/clr%20profiler.exe)

Answer (score 0):

I already used the profiler (ANTS Profiler) Now finally I found the reasons.

The problem is that in that winform application is a WPF Element host.
this takes about 25 MB unmanagedram (Ithinkg for the wpf environment), Then about 50MB are taken from  DevExpress and Infragistics controls :-(

This werent too many but i can reproduce it with the following controls of them:
1 Empty Grid
1 Empty Tree
1 RichtextCon1trol
1 Outlookpane

I think they both have some kind of framework which is initialised